# Как сохранить данные после закрытия приложения и восстановить их при повторном открытии?

Tags: android, activity

Пользователь вводит данные в определенные поля. Мне нужно сохранить эти данные в таком виде даже, если пользователь закроет приложение. Можете подсказать как такое реализовать?

[image: Пример моего Activity]

Comment: Используйте `SharedPreferences`, запись в базу данных SQLite, либо запись в файл, в зависимости от типа и количества данных, требуемых для сохранения. Для сохранения данных, аналогичных представленным на скриншотах, лучше всего подойдет работа с базой данных.

Comment: @pavlofff уже вышло сделать с SharedPreferences, не уверен, что мне нужна БД, ибо сохраняю эти данные только, чтобы пользователь не вводил их повторно при включении.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Мой предыдущий ответ был ошибочным, вам необходимо использовать `Preferences`. 
Получаете сам объект в `onCreate()`:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
  "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

И сохраняете значение переменной в `onStop()`

```
prefs.edit().putString("tag", editText.getText().toString()).apply();
```

В методе `onStart()` данные получаете обратно

```
ediText.setText(prefs.getString("tag", ""));
```

В нашем случае, сохраненные переменные будут храниться внутри нашего приложения, в папке `shared_pref`, внутри файла `com.example.app.xml`. Xml будет выглядеть так:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
    <string name="tag">editTextString</string>
</map>
```

Comment: Я сделал как вы сказали, но не пойму почему тут ругается: "Cannot resolve method getString()".

Comment: @Kostya Поправил, сначала необходимо вызвать getText(), а после toString()

Comment: Спасибо, для одного поля сработало, буду делать для других.

Comment: @iamtihonov можете еще подсказать, где будут храниться эти данные в файловой системе?

Comment: @Kostya Добавил в ответ

Comment: @iamtihonov большое спасибо.